# What do F and D mean at the end of numeric literals?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I've seen some of this symbols, but I cannot find anything strange with it,

```
double d = 5D;
float f = 3.0F;
```

What does the D and F behind 5 exactly means?

Comment: For those coming from C: 1) `d` suffix does not exist in ANSI C, only as a GNU extension. 2) `1f` is not possible in C, you must use `1.0f`. 3) For hex integer literls, `d` and `f` don't work as they would be ambiguous with the number itself, e.g. `0x1f` is `31`, not `1.0f`

Comment: Note that in C with GCC, even `5D` is invalid as being an integer constant; `5.D` would be OK. ICC 15 silently regards such numbers as 0. And with tcc 0.9.27, one gets a compile-time error.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Means that these numbers are doubles and floats, respectively. Assume you have

```
void foo(int x);
void foo(float x);
void foo(double x);
```

and then you call

```
foo(5)
```

the compiler might be stumped. That's why you can say `5`, `5f`, or `5.0` to specify the type.

Comment: with this, is 5.0 == 5d?

Comment: @Ungeheuer Yes. "A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 22):

D stands for double

F for float

you can read up on the basic primitive types of java here

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

I would like to point out that writing

5.1D or 5.1 : if you don't specify a type letter for a comma number then by default it is double

5 : without the period, by default it is an int

Answer (score 6):

They're format specifiers for float and double literals.  When you write `1.0`, it's ambiguous as to whether you intend the literal to be a float or double.  By writing `1.0f`, you're telling Java that you intend the literal to be a float, while using `1.0d` specifies that it should be a double.  There's also `L`, which represents long (e.g., `1L` is a `long` 1, as opposed to an `int` 1)

Comment: To clarify: it is not ambiguous to javac, only potentially to less experienced programmers. JLS says that `1.0` without suffix is a double.

Answer (score 2):

D stands for double and F stands for float.  You will occasionally need to add these modifiers, as 5 is considered an integer in this case, and 3.0 is a double.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned they are the Type definitions, however you will less likely see i or d mentioned as these are the defaults.

```
float myfloat = 0.5;
```

will error as the 0.5 is a double as default and you cannot autobox down from double to float (64 -> 32 bits) but

```
double mydouble = 0.5;
```

will have no problem

Comment: *"autobox"* is the wrong terminology for what you describe. What you mean is the opposite of promotion, which would be demotion, but there are no (automatic) rules for that.

Comment: I just did the Oracle java SE8 Java Programmer course, its right here in the notes, defaults and the fact that autoboxing/unboxing does not occur with reduction of precision and so type definition is required or casting for reduction of precision. as the type definition

Comment: [Autoboxing/unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) occurs when one (or the compiler) "converts" a primitive type to its corresponding wrapper type `int` -> `Integer`. What you're talking about is the opposite of [promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java) and yes, there is no automatic conversion due to the lost of precision.

Answer (score -2):

It defines the datatype for the constants 5 and 3.0.