# What does suffix 'f' mean in Java code?

Tags: java

Here's the explanatory code. The language is Java and the code uses Android.

```
fg.setTextSize(height*0.50f); //<-'f' is in the brackets
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    sWidth = w / 3f; // <-'f' is here
}
```

What does the suffix 'f' mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do F and D mean at the end of numeric literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331200/what-do-f-and-d-mean-at-the-end-of-numeric-literals)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It indicates a `float` literal.

Comment: Hard to understand for a guy coming from .NET :). Anyway, is it like casting? Is the same 3f and (float)3? What would happen if I omit it?

Comment: Then it would be an integer.
L is used for long, 
d for double

Comment: Dropping the f from w/3f will cause integer division to occur, rather than floating point division because 3 is an int while 3f is a float. Both 3f and ((float) 3) will evaluate to the same value, but (float) 3 may be converted at runtime, while 3f is always evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @askmo, the same thing works in .net.  EG if you want to declare a decimal literal, you can write it as `5m`, or look at the float example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @askmo: I'm not sure why this is so hard to understand, C# also uses f to represent float values, according to the [Value Types Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx).

Comment: Thanks guys. It wasn't hard to understand. I just haven't ever worked in such way in C#. Now it's clear. Thanks again.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong, ((float) 3) is a compile time constant, and will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: "3" is an integer, "3f" is a float, "3d" is a double.  Sometimes the distinction is important.  Sometimes javac is picky, e.g. "public static float FOO = 3.0" results in a "possible loss of precision" error because the values are assumed to be double by default.  (FWIW, "FOO = 3" works fine.)

Answer (score 5):

It indicates 3 is float not integer in other case 0.50 is float not double. Just like in any other java program.

Answer (score 2):

float ;)

it's a 3 that is a float, not an int

Answer (score 2):

It's a float, not a double. This is basic Java (C) notation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to append the f if entering 0 or 1 or during certain assignments. But other times you do need it especially when the compiler can't tell if its a float or a double or an int or needs to cast the value in some way. It's maddeningly inconsistent really.