# What does f means in animation

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does suffix ‘f’ mean in Android programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659517/what-does-suffix-f-mean-in-android-programming)

Excuse me if it was a stupid question, but I always see people writing something like 350f and 15f when initializing animations (passing as paramter) . What does f mean?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much, if you posted it  I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the format of the argument, FLOAT in this case.

Comment: So if you pass 15 alone, what would happen? It will still accept is as a float. Ther ehas to be a usge for this f

Comment: @Snake It depends on the method.  Imagine an overloaded method, someMethod(int value) and someMethod(float value).  To call the second one, you must pass a float, e.g. someMethod(15f); someMethod(15); will call the first.

Comment: @Snake `float i = 1/2;` (`i` will be `0.0`) vs `float j = 1f/2;` (`j` will be `0.5`).

Comment: @MattBall +1 for a much more complete answer.