# Instances went wrong from csv to weka

Tags: java, weka

```
 .csv
 100387C,254,73,93
 100388D,2047,60,98
 100388D,2736,62,9
 100389E,951,82,90
 100390F,2048,91,98
 100411C,254,50,96
 100412D,047,75,9

 .arff
 @relation test

 @attribute Admno {100387C,100388.0,100389E,100390.0,100411C,100412.0}
 @attribute Code {254,2047,2736,951,2048,254,047}
 @attribute ore numeric
 @attribute tend numeric
  100387C,254,73,93
  100388.0,2047,60,98
  100388.0,2736,62,9
  100389E,951,82,90
  100390.0,2048,91,98
  100411C,254,50,96
  100412.0,047,75,9
```

If you were to notice the different between this two data after converting was 
from D to .0 on @attribute Admno. The file conversion I was using are below. So I was wondering what went wrong on the conversion. Thanks

```
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File("C:\\test.csv"));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(data);
    saver.setFile(new File("C:\\test.arff"));
    saver.writeBatch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `100388D` as `100388.0` and `100390F` as `100390.0` is because the values are ending with D and F respectively. In Java, this means the values are Double and Float (D stands for Double and F stands for Float). That is why when Weka is converting them into nominal values, it is believing that the values should be Double or Float and hence the `.0` instead of `D` and `F`.

You can find a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331200/what-do-f-and-d-mean-at-the-end-of-numeric-literals) and the related documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no straight forward way to overcome this in `Weka`. But if this is an `ID` and does not take part into classification or clustering, then you can have the facility to ignore this attribute when you build a model based on this data and apply it on your test data.

Another way to overcome this is to change this attribute's values to some values that don't end with neither `D` nor `F`.

Comment: can it be done by editing the datatype in DatabaseUtilis.props?

Comment: @johny, you can try. I changed the field's data type on MS Excel but nothing worked. It seems like Weka is reading the values as plain text. But post here if you get a way around it.