# Round a double value to 10 digits in Java?

Tags: java, double

I was looking for a simple way to round a double value to 10 digits but I didn't found even one way that look good to me, everything was too complicated. 
I hope someone could help me, for example: the value 0.83426945721236485 will become 0.8342694572

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to round it or just remove all digits after the 10th? Also, do you mean 10 digits or 10 decimal places? Cause right now, you have 11 digits.

Comment: @Gendarme That the number of digits after the point should be rounded to 10 digits (i.e – 0.1234567891)

Comment: @shmosel I saw this thread already but there was too complicated solutions

Comment: What are you simplicity requirements?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/5221346) looks incredibly simple to me.

Comment: @shmosel using only the Math class and some algebra, can you help me with that please?

Comment: @Gendarme But I do not get what the "d" means at the value "100000d"

Comment: [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331200/what-do-f-and-d-mean-at-the-end-of-numeric-literals)

Comment: @Gendarme And someone in the comments said that this method fails 90% of the cases

Comment: Well, you are looking for a simple solution to something that is not simple. Computers count in binary. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/154354/5221346) is probably as simple as it gets.

Comment: @Gendarme Thank you for that link, it made me learn something :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000000");
System.out.println(df.format(0.83426945721236485));
```

Take a look at the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: But I can't see how it rounds an already given value, looks like you just print a number on the screen.

Comment: You're right. I spent the past 10 mins trying to come up with a primitive way to do rounding but couldn't find a short way without some nasty string concatenation and parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal places are not meaningful internally for double, because it is a binary floating point.

You can, of course, choose to display it in any format supported by DecimalFormat, as suggested in a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198056/1798593).

If you want a ten decimal place internal representation, you should be using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) with scale factor 10.