# Bitwise Operations on short

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am using a technology called DDS and in the IDL, it does not support `int`. So, I figured I would just use `short`. I don't need that many bits. However, when I do this:

```
short bit = 0;
System.out.println(bit);
bit = bit | 0x00000001;
System.out.println(bit);
bit = bit & ~0x00000001;
bit = bit | 0x00000002;
System.out.println(bit);
```

It says "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from int to short". When I change `short` to `long`, it works fine.

Is it possible to perform bitwise operations like this on a `short` in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When doing any arithmetic on `byte`, `short`, or `char`, the numbers are promoted to the wider type `int`. To solve your problem, explicitly cast the result back to `short`:

```
bit = (short)(bit | 0x00000001);
```

Links:

- Stack Overflow: [Promotion in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java)
- Java Language Specification section 5.6: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#26917

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that java does not support short literal values. But this did work for me:

```
short bit = 0;
short one = 1;
short two = 2;
short other = (short)~one;
System.out.println(bit);
bit |= one;
System.out.println(bit);
bit &= other;
bit |= two;
System.out.println(bit);
```