# Java Basic Operator Return Type

Tags: java

Is Java Operators return int type?

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2;

short c = a&b;
short d = a+b;
long e = a&b;
```

in case of 'c', 'd' they have type mismatch error. why?
and case of 'e' no error. why??

Comment: There are already several questions and answers in SO that answer this specific question. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015997/bitwise-operations-on-short), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100785/short-plus-short-is-an-int), ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any operation between two variables of integer type that are smaller than int results in an int. So:

```
short + short -> int
short + byte -> int
```

etc. It's mentioned in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2).

Therefore you have to cast the result of a + b to short in order to assign it back to a variable of type short. Please note, that you may lose data if you do so.

However `long` is bigger than `int`. The assigment ist valid.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is *binary numeric promotion*. This is specified in the Java Language Specification [§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Then it goes on to list the operators for which this applies to, which I won't quote here.

In all cases, both operands are `short`, so according to the last bullet, they are both converted to `int`. An `int` plus an `int` is another `int`, which can't be implicitly converted to a `short`. Hence the error in `c` and `d`. `int` is implicitly convertible to a `long`, though, so no error for `e`.