# Why can not I add two bytes and get an int and I can add two final bytes get a byte?

Tags: java, int, variable-assignment, scjp, ocpjp

```
public class Java{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final byte x = 1;
        final byte y = 2;
        byte z = x + y;//ok
        System.out.println(z);

        byte a = 1;
        byte b = 2;
        byte c = a + b; //Compiler error
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

If the result of an expression involving anything int-sized or smaller is always an int even if the sum of two bytes fit in a byte.

**Why does it happen when we add two final bytes that fit in a byte?** 
There is no compiler error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[From the JLS 5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> In addition, **if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int**:
>    - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>      variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>      expression is representable in the type of the variable.

In short the value of the expression (which is known at compile time, because it is a constant expression) is representable in the type of the variable that is byte.

Consider your expression

```
 final byte x = 1;
 final byte y = 2;
 byte z = x + y;//This is constant expression and value is known at compile time
```

So as summation fits into byte it does not raise an compilation error.

Now if you do

```
final byte x = 100;
final byte y = 100;
byte z = x + y;// Compilation error it no longer fits in byte
```

Comment: So, in summary, the OP is not seeing an error because he fortunately chose values which would sum to fit within a byte.

Comment: @Aubin Thanks Added the summary and detail description

Comment: But adding two int types is allowed. Even in case of int types, overflow may happen right? Why behavior is different with int and byte types?

Comment: Also, ["A compile-time *constant expression* is an expression \[…\] composed using only the following: • Literals of primitive type and literals of type `String`. \[…\] • The additive operators `+` and `-`. \[…\] • Simple names that refer to constant variables."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) Where ["A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and initialized with a compile-time constant expression, is called a *constant variable*."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

Comment: @Rajesh because binary operation (+) in java would return integer. You may need to cast explicitly byte c = (byte) (a + b); or to declare these byte fields final. However, the += operator does the cast for you. Say, if you have  byte a = 2, b = 3; then (a += b) gives you 5 as expected, neither explicit cast nor 'final' is needed.

Answer (score 10):

```
byte z = x + y;  // x and y are declared final
```

Here, since `x` and `y` are declared `final` so the value of expression on the `RHS` is known at compile time, which is fixed at `(1 + 2 = 3)` and cannot vary. So, you don't need to typecast it explicitly

```
byte c = a + b;   // a and b are not declared final
```

Whereas, in this case, value of `a` and `b` are not declared final. So, the value of expression is not known at compile time, rather is evaluated at runtime. So, you need to do an explicit cast.

---

However, even in the 1st code, if the value of `a + b` comes out to be outside the range `-128 to 127`, it will fail to compile.

```
final byte b = 121;
final byte a = 120;
byte x = a + b;  // This won't compile, as `241` is outside the range of `byte`

final byte b1 = 12;
final byte a1 = 12;
byte x1 = a1 + b1;  // Will Compile. byte can accommodate `24`
```

Comment: What appends if x = 120 and y = 120?

Comment: @Aubin.In that case, it would fail. Because 240 cannot be accommodated in byte.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we are  performing any arithmetic operation between two variable a & b the result is always,

```
max(int, type of a, type of b)

byte a=10;
byte b=20;
byte c=a+b(C.E )
```

*Explanation*: as described above
max(int, type of a, type of b)

max(int ,byte,byte)

the result is of type: int , found is int but required in byte

so we need to require typecast into  byte

```
    byte a=10;
    byte b=20;
    byte c=(byte) (a+b);
```

Comment: can you please explain why do we have to cast the sum of a,b to byte as `byte c=(byte) (a+b);`, why this throws error? `byte c=(a+b);`?