# final characters in Java

Tags: java, char, final

The following segment of code issues a compile-time error.

```
char c = 'c';
char d = c + 5;
```

The error on the second line says,

```
possible loss of precision
  required: char
  found:    int
```

<sub>The error message is based on the NetBeans IDE.</sub>

---

When this character `c` is declared `final` like as follows.

```
final char c = 'c';
char d = c + 5;
```

The compiler-time error vanishes.

It is unrelated to the case of [final strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19418427/1391249)

What does the `final` modifier make a difference here?

Comment: Is the compiler smart enough to see that, in the second case, `c + 5` is constant?

Comment: Good question, the answer must be somewhere in the JLS... Let's wait until someone is so nice to find it.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21187200/1686291)

Comment: [Possible dulicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13100019/1686291)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason is that the [JLS #5.2 (Assignment conversion)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-300) says so:

> If the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int, a narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

In your example, `char c = 'c';` is not [a constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) but `final char c = 'c';` is.

The rationale is probably that the addition operator `+` first converts its operands to integers. So the operation could overflow unless everything is constant in which case the compiler can prove that there is no overflow.

Comment: Was just about to post it :)

Comment: I think this one belongs in Josh Bloch's *Jave Puzzlers* :)

Comment: I would add that even if c is not final, if you use += operator (it has an implicit casting, but c = c + i; don't), so c+=i is the same as c = (char)(c+1); Just in case you want to add it to the answer as a tip

Answer (score 16):

[When you apply the `+` operator to integral types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2-200)

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

In this case, the `char` values are promoted to `int` values.

Here

```
char c = 'c';
char d = c + 5;
```

because `c` is not a constant expression, the compiler **cannot** determine if the value of `c + 5` which is an `int` will be able to fit in a `char`.

In this

```
final char c = 'c';
char d = c + 5;
```

where `c` is a constant expression, the compiler **can** determine that the value of `c`, which is `99`, added to `5`, which is `104` does fit in a `char`. **Because of this guarantee, Java can safely perform a narrowing conversion from `int` to `char`.**

If instead you had

```
final char a = Character.MAX_VALUE;     
char b = (a + 5);
```

you would see the similar behavior as your first test case as the value of `a + 5` does not fit in a `char`. The compiler determines that the `int` value resulting from `a + 5` would not fit in a `char`.

Comment: +1 better explanation in IMHO.

Comment: +1, better as it explicitly states that in the compilers' view, `c` could change between those statements.