# Using Different Data types

Tags: java

```
public class UnIntentionalObjectCreation {

  private static Byte sumOfIntegerUptoN(Byte N) {
    Byte sum = 0;
    for (Byte i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sumOfIntegerUptoN(10);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((end - start));

  }
}
```

Error in 6 line :- Inconvertible type found
Error in 14 line:- UnIntentionalObjectCreation cannot be applined to (int)

Comment: Change all of your Bytes to ints

Answer (score 1):

So your method accepts a `Byte`, while you are passing an `int`.
You can simply replace `Byte` variables/methods with `int`.

```
public class UnIntentionalObjectCreation {

  private static int sumOfIntegerUptoN(int N) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sumOfIntegerUptoN(10);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((end - start));

  }
}
```

Should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

`Byte` is an object but his behaviour is different form `Integer`, `Long` and `Double`, you cannot use it for basic arithmetic operations. And even if you can assign an integer number to a Byte object like this:

```
Byte a = 10;
```

Quite strangely, you cannot pass an integer number as parameter like you did calling `sumOfIntegerUptoN` method.

In your case, instead of a `Byte` I suggest to use a primitive data type like an `int`.

`Byte` object is immutable, so you cannot increment and decrement it.

> The Byte class wraps a value of primitive type byte in an object. An
>   object of type Byte contains a single field whose type is byte.

You should have a look at what is [autoboxing and autounboxing in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and which kind of [primitive data type exists in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

There is also another aspect I suggest to take care, a Byte is only 8 bit, so the range of number your can handle is quite small (-128/+127).

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I could notice -

**One**

```
sumOfIntegerUptoN(10); // this is expected to be of Type
```

which can be modified as -

```
sumOfIntegerUptoN(((Integer)10).byteValue()); // wraps the integer converted to byte into Byte
```

**Two**

```
sum += i; //where both these are Byte
```

the operation is not permitted according to the [doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). Since the values of the variables in the expression above are not known at the compile time.

As it happens in your case, do take a look at [Why can not I add two bytes and get an int and I can add two final bytes get a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100019/why-can-not-i-add-two-bytes-and-get-an-int-and-i-can-add-two-final-bytes-get-a-b)

Hence would recommend changing all the `Byte` occurrences in your code to `int` and perform operations accordingly.