# Data type of Literals/Result of Arithmetic operations on Literals in Java

Tags: java, literals, primitive-types, arithmetic-expressions

Can anybody please clarify the below:

```
byte a = 10 + 20; // b=30;
-------------
byte b=10,c=20;
byte a = b + c; //error. Casting required.
```

What was the data type of result of addition in the first line before assigning it to 'a'? Do literals have a data type. Or do arithmetic result assign them one ?

Comment: read also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100019/why-can-not-i-add-two-bytes-and-get-an-int-and-i-can-add-two-final-bytes-get-a-b

Answer (score 1):

since b + c is an operation that can overflow you need to do

```
byte a = (byte)(b + c);
```