# Mathematical operations on Java primitives?

Tags: java, java-7, primitive-types

I am trying to remember what happens when various mathematical operations are applied to Java Primitives e.g. `int + int = int`

But would would happen in this case:

```
float/short=?
```

Is there any easy way to remember what happens when any operation is applied to any of the Java primitives? Or is it just something that I will need to commit to memory?

--EDIT--

The `float/short` was an example of the kind of thing im looking for. Im wondering if there is a pattern on the answers when any operation is applied to any amount of primitives e.g.

```
double*double=?
short/byte+long=?
etc.....
```

Comment: Im not sure this is a duplicate? Im not looking for a specific operation or primitive I am looking for an answer for all operations on all primitive combinations

Comment: `short` will be promoted to `int` in math operations, the result is `float` according to widening  conversions (`int` -> `float`)

Comment: The general rule is the one of binary numeric promotion, as answered in the linked question: when doing operations on primitive types: if one of them is `double` (resp. `float`, resp. `long`), the other is converted to `double` (resp. `float`, resp. `long`); otherwise they are all converted to `int`. So the `short` in `float / short` is widened to a `float`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660864/1743880

Comment: If it is a duplicate, include the reference to the original.

Comment: Im not sure its duplicate but there is a reference at the top of the question

Comment: Please  see edit and consider reopening question

Comment: @Srb1313711 The general rule for all primitive types, which is your question, is mentioned the linked question. It is also mentioned here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660864/1743880.

Comment: Ok thanks, might be worth making the link in your comment the result of the duplicate instead of the current one

Comment: The links of “duplicate” messages always point to questions. So in either case, you have to scroll down to the first answer to find out that it explains the general rule.