# Why is there no need to explicitly cast in case of integers?

Tags: java, casting, integer

```
byte a=10;
byte b=20;

b=a+b;
```

In this case, I need to explicitly convert `a+b` to byte like this :

```
b=(byte)(a+b);
```

It's the same with short :

```
short x=23;
short y=24;
```

Otherwise it gives an error.

But in case of integers, it's not required to convert explicitly :

```
int p=7788;
int q=7668;

p=p+q;
```

This will work just fine.

Why is that?

We don't need to explicitly cast even in the case of long as well.

Comment: Because the result of any arithmetic operation is at least an integer wide, and an integer is already an integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the JLS [4.2.2 Integer Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2), it states that the result of a numerical operation between two integral operands is an `int` or a `long`. Since there's no implicit cast from an `int` to `byte` or a `short`, you need an explicit cast.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to [JLS Sec 15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2), which deals with addition of numeric types, it says:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> ...
>
> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.

[JLS Sec 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) describes *binary numeric promotion*:

> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

So, in the case of `int` and `long` (where both operands are of that type), binary numeric promotion is a no-op: the operands remain `int` and `long` respectively, and the result of the addition is `int` and `long` respectively, meaning the result can be assigned to variables of that type.

In the case of `byte` and `short`, binary numeric promotion causes both of those to be widened to `int` to perform the addition, and the result of the addition is `int`; you have to explicitly cast back again to the narrower type, because not all `int` values fit into a `byte` or `short`.

---

There are 2 exceptions to this requirement to do an explicit narrowing cast.

Firstly, compound assignments: this would have worked:

```
b += a;
```

because, as stated in [JLS Sec 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

In other words: the compiler inserts the cast for you:

```
b = (byte) ((b) + (a));
```

Secondly, if the operands have constant values, and the result of the addition is known to fit into the range of the narrower type, **and** you are doing the assignment at the variable declaration.

For example:

```
final byte a=10;  // final is necessary for a and b to be constant expressions.
final byte b=20;

byte c = a + b;
```

This requires no cast.

Comment: if we take value of a and b such as sum of a+b is greater than 127 its still giving error
if we take a=70 and b=80

final byte a=70;  
final byte b=80;

byte c = a + b;
will give error
same is the case when value of a+b is less than -128

Comment: @rajkumar.11 "and the result of the addition is known to fit into the range of the narrower type".

Answer (score 2):

With addition in java, java will promote the smaller data type to the larger one. And when the data type is smaller than int it will promote both the operant to int. Take a look at: [Promotion in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java)

Comment: It's not very precise to say "smaller data type": a `long` will be promoted to a `float`, and even though `float` is smaller in the sense that it's 32 bits vs `long`'s 64 bits.