# Adding Byte and Short

Tags: java, casting, calculation, primitive, primitive-types

I added a `Byte` variable to a `Short` variable, however I had to add `(Short)` for the line of code to compute. I thought this was not needed as I'm adding a smaller data type to a bigger one. Why is this?

What i thought was correct.

```
        byte NumberOfShoes = 5;
        short Laces = 10;
        short ShoePacks = NumberOfShoes + Laces;
        System.out.println(ShoePacks);
```

What was correct.

```
        byte NumberOfShoes = 5;
        short Laces = 10;
        short ShoePacks = (short) (NumberOfShoes + Laces);
        System.out.println(ShoePacks);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promotion in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java) (the duplicate is mainly about bytes, but the same things happen here: operands are converted to `int` and then added)

Comment: *tl;dr* `byte` and `short` are not general purpose numeric variables in Java and will be hard to use for stuff like that. Just use `int` and cast down were necessary (plus probably checking for overflow).